MTB Loss of drive traction when taking off from a dead stop, or pedalling hard uphill
A little oddity with my bike.
When I pull off from stationary, or push down hard on the pedal in a high gear, the pedals momentarily slip like there isn't any traction. After maybe 1/5 of a pedal rotation, the traction comes back, and all is normal.
There is no chain skip, or anything ... that's all fine ... nothing "external".
Nothing odd in the front cogs at all, it is definitely slipping in the rear.
It feels just like a car slipping on the clutch - as if there is too much power for the clutch to grip enough to turn it all into rotation
Any ideas what that could be ?
Background info
I have just got my bike back from a service and tune-up. The back axle was replaced, and the bike was mostly stripped down, clean and reassembled. That may be related as I have never had this behaviour before.
It's a standard MTB ... 3 front and 7 rear.
Additional Info
I did do some googling first guys, but all the searches came up with problems related to the chain slipping over sprockets and gears.
Edit
Deleted Freehub and Pawls theory.
Additional Info 2
Leaning now to a Freewheel explanation as per the answer from @noise
I will test tomorrow as per my comment below his answer.
- - - Final Edit - - -
@noise was correct.

I can no longer reproduce the problem; my legs have tightened up all the slack in the hand fitting.

The bike shop guy took one look at the rear gear set and said: "Yup, that's a freewheel and not a cassette." He gave the pedal a solid crank and couldn't get any more slippage out of it.


Problem solved.

Check if your cassette is on tight. Take the wheel off and see if the outer cogs are loose. Dt Swiss hubs are known to come loose. If Shimano, they may not have been torqued correctly.

7 speed rear could be a freewheel (see What is the difference between a freewheel and a hub?). That could be damaged and needed to be replaced. Given that the wheel was just serviced, incorrect assembly is more likely though.

@JohnnyFivern DT Swiss hubs are known to come loose — uh, beg your pardon?

@linac Incorrect assembly seems like an option. They told me that the back axle had snapped, and they replaced it. I'll take it back to them on Saturday to have it properly checked.

@paul h https://www.reddit.com/r/wheelbuild/comments/tf3090/dt_swiss_350_loose_free_hub/. I missed that it’s a 7 speed, so moot point.

It's gonna take more than a single yahoo on reddit to back up that claim, IMO (especially when all of the responses indicate it’s a non-issue for where the OP is in the reassembly process)

That was just the first link on a google search. I’ve seen threads all over the place about the issue. Canyon forums, youtube videos, etc. it’s not a horrible thing, but it’s a thing.

@PaulH They’re probably just referring to how DT freehubs can easily be pulled off the hub shell. Has nothing to do with the ratchet operation itself though…

@JohnnyFiver throwing things into Google and then dropping in links that you think support a claim, when in fact they don’t, really isn’t how this site operates. At least review the information you purport to make your case.

Thanks for the edits to confirm the diagnosis of the problem. Enjoy the refreshed bike!

It's not so odd: nearly every new bike does this.
I expect you won't have the effect any more after a couple of steep hills.
Axles most often break on hubs designed for freewheels. Most 7sp new bikes are freewheel clusters. (freehubs on 8sp and up.)
The bike shop generally will remove the 7sp freewheel to replace an axle as some of the seals etc don't clear the freewheel centre hole.
Once it goes back together, the freewheel is screwed on by hand, leaving the rider to fully tighten it with the action of the chain over the first few rides. It feels exactly like your description. Bike shops that test ride repairs won't show this symptom to the customer.
The same effect can be observed on some freehub wheels where a ratchet ring is threaded into the hub for the pawls to engage. The design is quite common.
There is no fault.

Thanks!. That all makes sense. I do kind of remember it happening the first few times I went for a ride after the axle-replacement, and it not happening the last few times. So your explanation would be that I tightened up the "loose hand fitting" with my "leg power". I will try some "high torque" pull offs tomorrow to see if I can reproduce the symptom.

✅ Yup. Confirmed that your answer was correct for my situation.
